# Why hierarchical clustering with pvclust and hclust gives different results?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am performing the hierarchical clustering analysis on a dataset of 25 viral populations using 3 viral components (variables) to construct a dendrogram with average method and correlation distance calculation. We firstly used the `hclust()` method generate a plot, but we still need to support the dendrogram by statistical analysis. So after transposing the data, we choose `pvclust()` to generate the dendrogramm. However, the plots constructed by `pvclust` and the one generated by `hclust` are totally different. We used the same data and same parameters (average method and correlation distance), but the results are so different. Why might this be? [Here](https://github.com/yingfengisu/RSHOP/blob/master/TVA1.csv) is the dataset.

## hclust

> [image]

```
######### hclust method #############
sd.data = scale(tav.data)
dd = as.dist(1-cor(t(sd.data)))  # correlation-based distance
plot(hclust(dd, method="average"), xlab="", sub="", 
     main="Average Linkage with Correlation-Based Distance", labels=tav.labs)
```

> [image]

---

## pvclust

> [image]

```
######### pvclust method ################
tav.data0 = tav.data[,c(1,2,3)]
rownames(tav.data0) <- tav.labs
tav.data0 = as.data.frame(t(tav.data0))
sd.data0 = scale(tav.data0)
library(pvclust)
result = pvclust(sd.data0, method.hclust="average", method.dist="correlation", 
                 nboot=100, r=seq(0.7,1.4,by=.1))
plot(result)
```

> [image]

Comment: They are two different methods so what makes you think they will return the same answers?

Comment: @Dan,Because the pvclust mentioned they used the same method as hclust

Comment: Can you give the whole data (and in text, please)? How can one check without the data?

Comment: I could reproduce your second dendrogram by clustering in SPSS, but failed to do it for your first dendrogram. You might be doing something wrong in your 1st case. Check if your first 2 statements there give you exactly the same distance matrix as the matrix in your second case.

Answer (score 3):

You said you transposed your data before using pvclust.

Using hclust() is 2 steps: first make a distance matrix with dist(), then feed that into hclust()

Using pvclust is 1 step: feed your data table directly into pvclust().

The format for dist() and pvclust() is the same, so you should not have transposed your data.  Both ways you end up clustering columns according to rows.

Comment: No: `hclust` by default looks at rows of passed dataframes, `pvclust` by default looks at columns. Hence, without transposing, with `pvclust` you would get a dendrogram of features instead of samples, when `hclust` gives you a dendrogram of samples for the same input. As a result, and contrary to this answer, transposing would be correct - just in case anybody runs into this answer.

Comment: @geekoverdose I think the issue was that they should not have transposed before using `dist`. Has been a while, but takeaway from this comment remains: double check how rows and columns are changing in your workflow!